# Programmatically settings the Field of View in Unity results in wrong values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fieldofview

I'm playing with a camera in Unity where I change it's properties via a script. One of [the property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html) change is the `Camera.fieldOfView`. This property is dependant on the Focal length and the sensor size.

For a fixed focal length, I compute the sensor size for a desired field of view. When I assign the sensor size and focal length, the field of view computed by Unity doesn't match the expected one.

My calculation are similar to [these ones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41273/how-to-calculate-the-fov-in-degrees-from-focal-length-or-distance) and seems correct.

Does Unity use another model for its camera than the Pinholde model? Where could the discrepencies come from?

Comment: You're probably using [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had I read [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html) carefully, I would have known that `Camera.fieldOfView` is defined as:

> This is the vertical field of view; horizontal Field of view varies depending on the viewport's aspect ratio.

My computation were for the horizontal field of view and I didn't realized that I was assigning to the vertical field of view of the camera. The field of view displayed was therefore consistently off by a factor equal to the sensor aspect ratio.

In Unity, you need [to adjust both the camera's `fieldOfView` and `aspect` to adjust the horizontal field of view](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-use-horizontal-field-of-view-in-unity.280689/)